# Laravel Sum with where and alias with Eloquent

Tags: laravel, codeigniter, eloquent, sum

I have this query for an old Codeigniter project:

```
$this->db->select("SUM(source = 'FBS) AS facebook");
$this->db->select("SUM(source = 'FBS' AND promotion = 0) AS facebook_promotion");
$this->db->select("SUM(source = 'IG') AS instagram");
$this->db->select("SUM(source = 'LP') AS landing_page");
```

I'd like to have same result using Laravel, if is possible with Eloquent instead of Query Builder or Raw Query.

Comment: Instead of Eloquent Query Builder, you can use Eloquent Model like, Model::where('source','=','FBS')->sum('source'); And with query builder, it could be, DB::table('table_name')->where('source','=','FBS')->sum('source');

Comment: @Abdullah Al Farooq thanks for help. I already tried it, but not understand how can add multiple sum with aliases for each column in a single query .

Comment: @mustaine please don't write an answer in the Question area. You can self-answer your Question following: [**Can I answer my own question**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: @Vickel sorry I forgot it. Done now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use raw Query Builder, it would be like,

```
DB::table('table_name')->where('source','=','FBS')->sum('source');
```

For Eloquent Models,

```
 Model::where('source','=','FBS')->sum('source')
```

It also works with eloquent relationship.

Besides, for multiple sum results like yours, it would be like,

```php
DB::table('table_name')->get( array(
  DB::raw("SUM(source = 'FBS) AS facebook"),
  DB::raw("SUM(source = 'FBS' AND promotion = 0) AS facebook_promotion"),
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved in this way using DB::raw;

```
$data = CONTACT::select(
    DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%m-%d-%Y")),
    DB::raw('SUM(source = "IG") as instagram'),
    DB::raw('SUM(source = "FBS") as facebook')
)
->orderBy('data', 'DESC')
->groupBy(DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%d-%m-%Y')"))
->get();
return response()->json(['success' => $data], 200);
```